# Select Specific Rows based Simple Rules

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have sample data that looks like this

```
Id  UserId  EventDate   EventId EventTime               Fg  RN
1   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:10.000 0   8
2   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:11.000 0   7
3   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:12.000 1   6
4   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:13.000 1   5
5   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:15.000 0   4
6   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:17.000 0   3
7   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:20.000 1   2
8   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:25.000 1   1
9   1       2018-10-16  8       2018-10-16 12:12:33.000 0   3
10  1       2018-10-16  8       2018-10-16 12:12:43.000 0   2
11  1       2018-10-16  8       2018-10-16 12:12:47.000 1   1
12  1       2018-10-17  9       2018-10-17 12:15:10.000 0   4
13  1       2018-10-17  9       2018-10-17 12:15:15.000 0   3
14  1       2018-10-17  9       2018-10-17 12:15:18.000 1   2
15  1       2018-10-17  9       2018-10-17 12:15:25.000 1   1
```

I want select the following rows

```
Id  UserId  EventDate   EventId EventTime               Fg  RN
7   1       2018-10-15  6       2018-10-15 12:10:20.000 1   2
11  1       2018-10-16  8       2018-10-16 12:12:47.000 1   1
14  1       2018-10-17  9       2018-10-17 12:15:18.000 1   2
```

These rows are identified by next row following the first `Fg` column being 0 starting from the end going backwards.  The End is identified by the `RN` column being 1.

For further clarification, the `RN` column is the order of events for each UserId for each day starting from the end going backwards.

The solution I have working is a Recursive CTE traversing backwards but this quite slow for the amount of data I have.

What alternatives approaches are there?

Here's the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), UserId INT, EventDate DATE, EventId INT, EventTime DATETIME NOT NULL, Fg BIT, RN BIGINT)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test(UserId, EventDate, EventTime, Fg, RN, EventId ) 
VALUES
     (1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:10', 0, 8, 6)
    ,(1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:11', 0, 7, 6)
    ,(1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:12', 1, 6, 6)
    ,(1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:13', 1, 5, 6)

    ,(1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:15', 0, 4, 6)
    ,(1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:17', 0, 3, 6)
    ,(1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:20', 1, 2, 6)
    ,(1, '20181015','20181015 12:10:25', 1, 1, 6)

    ,(1, '20181016','20181016 12:12:33', 0, 3, 8)
    ,(1, '20181016','20181016 12:12:43', 0, 2, 8)
    ,(1, '20181016','20181016 12:12:47', 1, 1, 8)

    ,(1, '20181017','20181017 12:15:10', 0, 4, 9)
    ,(1, '20181017','20181017 12:15:15', 0, 3, 9)
    ,(1, '20181017','20181017 12:15:18', 1, 2, 9)
    ,(1, '20181017','20181017 12:15:25', 1, 1, 9)
GO
```

Comment: The trick here is that you have to use something to define the order. Can we use the Id column to order? Do you have something in your real data to use for ordering?

Comment: Very well done question, btw.

Comment: @SeanLange You mean other than the EventTime and RN columns? The Id column can be used to Order.

Comment: "The solution I have working" post that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use window functions to help identify the right records here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventID, LagCheck ORDER BY RN) lagCheckRow
        FROM
            (
                SELECT test.*, lag(Fg) OVER (PARTITION BY EventID ORDER BY RN DESC) as lagcheck
                FROM test
            ) t1
    ) t2
WHERE lagCheckRow = 1 AND lagCheck = 0;


+----+--------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----+----------+-------------+
| Id | UserId |      EventDate      | EventId |      EventTime      |  Fg  | RN | lagcheck | lagCheckRow |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----+----------+-------------+
|  7 |      1 | 15.10.2018 00:00:00 |       6 | 15.10.2018 12:10:20 | True |  2 | 0        |           1 |
| 11 |      1 | 16.10.2018 00:00:00 |       8 | 16.10.2018 12:12:47 | True |  1 | 0        |           1 |
| 14 |      1 | 17.10.2018 00:00:00 |       9 | 17.10.2018 12:15:18 | True |  2 | 0        |           1 |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+------+----+----------+-------------+
```

[Rextester.com example](https://rextester.com/SSC23485)

The inner most query uses `Lag()` to get the previous record's `Fg`. We want a `0` here (filtered in the outer most query). Then we hit that `Row_Number()` to get an order from that lag() result. We keep the one where that order = 1.

This should be MUCH quicker than a recursive cte since it only has to take about 4 swipes at the data (initial result set, window function run, next window function run, final WHERE predicate).

Quick note: If this table has more than one `userid` (certainly it does) and this is going to be run against more than just one, then add `userid` into each `PARTITION BY` to insure you don't end up with wacky answers.